# Mecha anime where the hero gets two robot suits

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

What is the name of the mecha anime where the hero uses one mobile suit but when the battle gets tough he calls for another suit that comes from somewhere and takes him in?

I saw it on Cartoon Network, not Adult Swim, maybe in the 90’s. I recently remembered some scenes and it has been bothering me. I try to see if that is Mobile Suit Gundam but could not find the exact plot.

The first suit is larger and the second is the size a bit larger than human. The smaller one uses swords and it is fast and agile.  It comes when called and after the fight it leaves the hero to return to its place somewhere in space.

Comment: "I recently remembered some scenes" - do you remember anything besides what you've already put in the question? If so, please [edit] any details in - nothing is too small to include!

Comment: See [our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/102999) for help improving your question.

Answer (score 3):

Found it! *Ninja robots* is its English name. *[Ninja Senshi Tobikage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja_Senshi_Tobikage)* is the original name.

Now I can sleep in peace. Thanks, guys, you helped me to think deep and then I searched Google Images.

This title song brought back the memory!!

Comment: You should merge your accounts so you gain the reputation from the question and the answer, and then you should come back and self-accept this answer in 2 days so other people know it's correct.